# Word for when you think of anyone and they call you

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there a word when you think of someone and he suddenly shows up or calls you ?

Comment: Yes, there is: **coincidence**.

Comment: OK. So, we can use "coincidence" not just in events but also when we think of them.

Comment: @Bobson: corrected the title

Comment: Looking for 'Love'?

Answer (score 1):

Could the word you want be *[synchronicity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synchronicity)*:-

> 1. Coincidence of events that seem to be meaningfully related, conceived in Jungian theory as an explanatory principle on the same
>      order as causality. [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

Comment: As I understand the theory, for this word to apply, you need to have 2 or more events that are seemingly very similar or identical, but causally unrelated  ("an apparently meaningful coincidence in time of two or more similar or identical events that are causally unrelated" Collins English Dictionary from thefreedictionary.com)  For instance, one person drops dead of a heart attack and the same day so does his brother-in-law who lives in another state.  That's nothing like what the question describes!

Answer (score 0):

Probably most accurate is "anomolous experience".

I've heard this meaning associated with "premonition".  Some people say "sixth sense" (but, more technically, psychologists will call it an "anomolous experience" which is why I mentioned that first).  I've also heard this intended meaning from the phrase "feminine intuition".  Men will often say "gut feeling" or something more along those lines.

Here's an on-point article from Psychology Today:  http://www.psychologytoday.com/articles/201206/your-sixth-sense

Comment: this one also seem to relate to what I was searching for but this is more of a technical word. Isn't it ?

Comment: Are you asking is it more technical than synchronicity?  They are equally technical, but I think the most important thing to consider is that synchronicity DOES NOT describe what you ask in the question - you would need 2 nearly identical but seemingly unrelated events for it to apply - such as you and 3 long-forgotten classmates from years ago all decide to vacation at the same hotel in Athens, Greece at the same time.  What your question describes is "anomolous experience" not "synchronicity"; black and white difference between the two.